# enterprise library dbcommand AddInParameter method for Oracle

Tags: c#, unicode, oracle11g, nvarchar

My question is very similar to this question - [Addin parameter for Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235135/enterprise-library-dbcommand-addinparameter-method) except that i'm using Oracle 11g. The datbase has two different charactersets for `VARCHAR(Western European)` and `NVARCHAR(Unicode)` datatypes.

```
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "nationalColumn", DbType.String, "高野")
```

National characterset in the database is unicode and so NVARCHAR columns are able to hold these characters.

My question is how do i tell db.AddInParameter function that the parameter i'm adding is a  NVARCHAR and not a VARCHAR which it seems to be assuming by default.

Adding to this - I'm using System.Data.OracleClient to connect to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as i spent a week figuring it out. The System.Data namespace doesn't understand that the column it's handling is a national column unless it is specified explicitly as OracleType.Nvarchar.

To resolve the situation above, I had to override the AddInParameter function to add a switch case that checks if the input DBType is a String and map it to a OracleType.NVarchar.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can't encode Chinese characters in the Western Europe encoding. This encoding has a limited number of characters defined and they don't include Chinese.

What output did you expect? I'd expect either the data to be garbled or an error to be returned.

Comment: National characterset in the database is unicode and so NVARCHAR columns are able to hold these characters. My question is how do i tell db.AddInParameter function that the parameter i'm adding is a NVARCHAR column and not a VARCHAR column  which it seems to be assuming by default

Comment: That is an entirely different question than the one you asked. I don't know the answer. I guess you need to ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry if i didn't communicate correctly. i'll put in an edit.

Comment: Is the parameter to the procedure declared as NVARCHAR and is everything NVARCHAR in the path of the data?

Comment: Yes. I'm calling a stored proc and it contains only a simple insert into a table

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the parameters yourself or are you letting Enterprise Library try to find out the parameters type?
If you are calling

```
command.AddInParameter(“parameterName”, value);
```

try calling the procedure and let Enterprise Library find out the parameters, like this example:

```
DB.ExecuteNonQuery(“PKG_USER.DELETE”, userId);
```

The procedure expects an `INT` parameter called `P_ID`, but the command only pass in the parameter value. EntLib uses the parameters order to send them.

Also take a look at

- this other post that I wrote: http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/enterprise-library-5-with-odp-net/
- this sample code: https://github.com/stanleystl/EntLib5ODP.NET
- and this stack overflow answer: [C#/Oracle: Specify Encoding/Character Set of Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535773/c-oracle-specify-encoding-character-set-of-query)

Comment: Thanks for this. This approach automatically picks up DbType.String as the datatype. So didn't resolve the issue. It's apparent that the System.Data namespace implicitly doesn't support the National characterset if the primary character set is different. I had to put in a case statement that uses OracleType if a NVARCHAR column is involved